# How are option expiration dates decided?

Tags: american-options

I looked at the CBOE website and they say the expiration is the Saturday following the third Friday of each month.  However, I look up an options chain for Google, for example, and I see three expiration dates for May: May 3, 2013, May 10, 2013, May 18, 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard Options on CBOE expire on the Saturday following the third Friday of a [month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expiration_%28options%29). Additionally to that there exist [weekly options](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/11/intro-weekly-options.asp). That's why you see these two series of options.